# Does a geometric shape exists for which the length of the border is always a multiple of the area?

Tags: geometry

Does a geometric shape exist that depends on a single parameter $l$ and has the following properties:

- It is (=grows) smooth accoriding to "$l$" (e.g. like a circle or a square)
- Its area is $l^2$
- The length of its border is $cl^2$ for a fixed constant $c$
- It has no holes
- The shape may change (extremly) with a changing $l$ value, but this change has to be "smooth"

Does something like this exists?

Comment: is c=1 a possibility ?

Comment: Note that we necessarily have to impose some kind of lower limit on $l$: for $l < 2\sqrt{\pi}/c$ it will be impossible to enclose an area of size $l^2$ with a curve of length only $cl^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $\ell>2$ a rectangle $a(\ell)\times b(\ell)$,

\begin{align}
a(\ell)&=\frac{\ell}2\,(\ell-\sqrt{\ell^2-4})
,\\
b(\ell)&=\frac{\ell}2\,(\ell+\sqrt{\ell^2-4})
,\\
S&=a\,b = \ell^2
,\\
L&=2\,(a+b)=2\,\ell^2
.
\end{align}

Comment: See my comment on OP: even though this only works for $l>2$, it is impossible for any solution to work for all positive $l$, for dimensional analysis reasons.  So I think this is as good as can be expected.